# How to perform group by in sql

Tags: sql, function, group-by, grouping, sql-server-2016

[image: Displayed record in my crystal Report]

```
   SELECT [BarDetailId]
    ,[BarId]
    ,[Member]
    ,[MemberNo]
    ,[BarMark]
    ,[TypeSize]
    ,[BarLength]
    ,[BarNo]
    ,[BarTotal]
    ,[ShapeCode]
    ,[ShapeImage]
    ,(SELECT CASE WHEN DimA <> 0 THEN 'A=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimA AS 
   Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimB <> 0 THEN 
        ', B=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimB AS Decimal(18, 0)))
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimC <> 0 THEN 
        ', C=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimC AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimD <> 0 THEN 
        ', D=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimD AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimE <> 0 THEN 
        ', E=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimE AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimF <> 0 THEN 
        ', F=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimF AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimG <> 0 THEN 
        ', G=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimG AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimN <> 0 THEN 
        ', N=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimN AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END) AS Dimension
    ,[DimA]
    ,[DimB]
    ,[DimC]
    ,[DimD]
    ,[DimE]
    ,[DimF]
    ,[DimG]
    ,[DimN]
    ,[Remark]
    ,[Active]
    ,[CreatedDtTm]
    ,[CreatedBy]
    ,[CreatedIp]
    ,[UpdatedDtTm]
    ,[UpdatedBy]
    ,[UpdatedIp]
   FROM BAR_SCHEDULE_DETAIL WHERE Active = 1 AND BarId = @BarId
```

How to group them based on TypeSize, Shape Code. I want to include the group by statement but receive this error message. 
Column 'BAR_SCHEDULE_DETAIL.BarDetailId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP BY
```

Is used during an aggregate function like

`sum(), count(), min(), max(), avg()`

If you want to group the records together, each column is required to be either part of the

`GROUP BY`

clause, or be aggregated in some way using one of the functions above. More info can be found here:

http://www.sqlcourse2.com/agg_functions.html

I suspect you might mean you want the results ordered so that the groups of records are together, and you might be looking for the

`ORDER BY`

clause.

If you would only like all the combinations of the columns you commented on before, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT , 
    [TypeSize] , 
    [ShapeCode] , 
    CASE 
        WHEN dima <> 0 THEN 
             'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
        ELSE '' 
      END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimb <> 0 THEN 
               ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimc <> 0 THEN 
               ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimd <> 0 THEN 
               ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dime <> 0 THEN 
               ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimf <> 0 THEN 
               ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimg <> 0 THEN 
               ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimn <> 0 THEN 
               ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END
      AS dimension 
FROM            bar_schedule_detail 
WHERE           active = 1 
AND             barid = @BarId
```

In order to include the "top comment", if that means the first comment posted - then something like this would do it:

```
select a.*, b.remark from 
(
    SELECT
        [TypeSize] , 
        [ShapeCode] , 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dima <> 0 THEN 
                 'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
          END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimb <> 0 THEN 
                   ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimc <> 0 THEN 
                   ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimd <> 0 THEN 
                   ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dime <> 0 THEN 
                   ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimf <> 0 THEN 
                   ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimg <> 0 THEN 
                   ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimn <> 0 THEN 
                   ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END
          AS dimension,
          min(c.CreatedDtTm) as CreatedDtTm
    FROM            bar_schedule_detail c
    WHERE           active = 1 
    AND             barid = @BarId    
    GROUP BY
        [TypeSize] , 
        [ShapeCode] , 
        CASE 
            WHEN dima <> 0 THEN 
                 'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
          END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimb <> 0 THEN 
                   ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimc <> 0 THEN 
                   ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimd <> 0 THEN 
                   ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dime <> 0 THEN 
                   ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimf <> 0 THEN 
                   ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimg <> 0 THEN 
                   ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimn <> 0 THEN 
                   ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END
) as a, bar_schedule_detail b
where a.typesize = b.typesize
and a.shapecode = b.shapecode
and 
(
   CASE 
     WHEN b.dima <> 0 THEN 
          'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
   END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimb <> 0 THEN 
            ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimc <> 0 THEN 
            ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimd <> 0 THEN 
            ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dime <> 0 THEN 
            ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimf <> 0 THEN 
            ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimg <> 0 THEN 
            ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimn <> 0 THEN 
            ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END
) = a.dimension
and a.CreatedDtTm = b.CreatedDtTm
and b.active = 1 
and b.barid = @BarId
```

From here it gets increasingly more difficult without a copy of the DDL and some rows to test this answer with, but if you want to order by some arbitrary pieces of attributes, you might try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT , 
    [TypeSize] , 
    [ShapeCode] , 
    CASE 
        WHEN dima <> 0 THEN 
             'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
        ELSE '' 
      END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimb <> 0 THEN 
               ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimc <> 0 THEN 
               ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimd <> 0 THEN 
               ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dime <> 0 THEN 
               ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimf <> 0 THEN 
               ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimg <> 0 THEN 
               ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN dimn <> 0 THEN 
               ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
        END
      AS dimension 
FROM            bar_schedule_detail 
WHERE           active = 1 
AND             barid = @BarId
```

In order to include the "top comment", if that means the first comment posted - then something like this would do it:

```
select a.*, b.remark from 
(
    SELECT
        [TypeSize] , 
        [ShapeCode] , 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.dima <> 0 THEN 
                 'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
          END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimb <> 0 THEN 
                   ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimc <> 0 THEN 
                   ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimd <> 0 THEN 
                   ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dime <> 0 THEN 
                   ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimf <> 0 THEN 
                   ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimg <> 0 THEN 
                   ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN c.dimn <> 0 THEN 
                   ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(c.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END
          AS dimension,
          min(c.CreatedDtTm) as CreatedDtTm
    FROM            bar_schedule_detail c
    WHERE           active = 1 
    AND             barid = @BarId    
    GROUP BY
        [TypeSize] , 
        [ShapeCode] , 
        CASE 
            WHEN dima <> 0 THEN 
                 'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
            ELSE '' 
          END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimb <> 0 THEN 
                   ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimc <> 0 THEN 
                   ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimd <> 0 THEN 
                   ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dime <> 0 THEN 
                   ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimf <> 0 THEN 
                   ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimg <> 0 THEN 
                   ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END + 
            CASE 
                WHEN dimn <> 0 THEN 
                   ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
                ELSE '' 
            END
) as a, bar_schedule_detail b
where a.typesize = b.typesize
and a.shapecode = b.shapecode
and 
(
   CASE 
     WHEN b.dima <> 0 THEN 
          'A=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dima AS decimal(18, 0)))
     ELSE '' 
   END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimb <> 0 THEN 
            ', B=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimb AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimc <> 0 THEN 
            ', C=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimc AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimd <> 0 THEN 
            ', D=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimd AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dime <> 0 THEN 
            ', E=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dime AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimf <> 0 THEN 
            ', F=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimf AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimg <> 0 THEN 
            ', G=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimg AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END + 
     CASE 
         WHEN b.dimn <> 0 THEN 
            ', N=' + CONVERT(varchar, cast(b.dimn AS decimal(18, 0)))
         ELSE '' 
     END
) = a.dimension
and a.CreatedDtTm = b.CreatedDtTm
and b.active = 1 
and b.barid = @BarId    
ORDER BY
    substring(a.TypeSize,1,1) desc, 
    substring(a.TypeSize,2,len(a.TypeSize)-1)
```

Comment: In the result set, do you want one line representing the group, or do you want multiple lines where the groups of information with the same TypeSize and ShapeCode are next to eachother?

Comment: I want one line representing the group

Comment: what else do you want in the result set? besides the columns you are grouping by, what would you like to do with the rest of the colums, hide them? have a total on each line? have the average on each line?

Comment: What does "top remark" mean? Does that mean the first remark for a given typesize, shapecode, and dimension?

Comment: "top remark" is an ambiguous description in terms of SQL. Do you mean the remark with the earliest timestamp for a given set of attributes?

Comment: There's a much more efficient way to do this, but I'm about to fall asleep. I'll pass you some updated SQL in the morning which should not break Crystal.

Comment: added a half-asleep guess :D

Comment: cool. I'm glad it's working out! you're welcome, hit some up arrows if you feel it! -b

Comment: what's the data type of the attribute?

Comment: min() will give you the minimum (or first in the sort order) value for a given set of key attributes. I think you're more interested in the "top" record, for which you might need to rank your result set, or use self joins. I'd be happy to talk this over in more detail, would you like to exchange contact information?